# Google Cloud Storage and being charged for files not found

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Does anyone know if you are charged for a file request in Google Cloud Storage if the file doesn't exist?  In other words, does someone accessing a non-existent file in your bucket count against your requests?  Or is that only for files that exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customers are not charged for requests that result in a 400-level or 500-level HTTP response.

The only exception is for 404 responses returned for buckets that have [Website Configuration](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration) enabled with a custom `NotFoundPage` object.