# Google Cloud Storage: blob.exists() operation class

Tags: google-cloud-storage

As listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing), Google Cloud Storage operations are split into 3 classes: A/B/Free. I'd like to know to which class does `blob.exists()` (testing the existence of a file) belongs? I would have guessed it belonged to the B class but then found [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322925/google-cloud-storage-and-being-charged-for-files-not-found) that gives me reasons to think that could be free.

Answer (score 1):

I depends on whether the object is found or not, [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) does mention what is on the answer you found as a note bellow the operations chart.

However, as the method is performing a get by judging from [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob.exists), it should be considered as a B class operation in case that the object is found as it would not return a 307, 4xx, or 5xx.

Comment: Good catch, I did not check the source to see what it was actually doing... That being said, all the `blob.download_...` functions use `google.resumable_media.requests.*Download` behind the scene, while `exists()` is, as you mentioned, a simple `GET` operation that doesn't require streaming the actual payload. Maybe that makes a difference when it comes to billing?

Comment: You are right, this would be the difference in billing between operations. After all the operations are classified by the API, so depending on which method you are using behind the scenes, the pricing will change.